# How to make a jtextfield observable to many jframes

Tags: java

I need some help to figure out how can i make one text field observable to many frames .. it's like a messaging app all frames can send to that text field and all of them must get updates when it changes

Comment: Good question in general but it doesn't fit to SO rules...Please **visit** the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post codes and efforts!

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the JavaFX approach, as a JTextField does not have a *model* (as JTextPane does). *(Adding listeners to a view component is not entirely MVC.)*

Instead of updating the JTextField have a model: a [**StringProperty**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/StringProperty.html) and update that. Have one Observable listener to update the JTextField, and all others to update all the frames, using `addListener`.

Answer (score -1):

A JTextField has an underlying document that is a kind of model. To observe the text, you would do:

```
jTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Not correct. All Swing text editing components inherit from `JTextComponent` where the model resides.

Comment: Your original answer said that JTextField did not have a model.

Comment: So you down voted mine to get even? My answer is cleaner and more correct than yours. You shouldn't be spiteful.

Comment: @markbernard you must be confusing with another answer

Comment: @markbernard my downvote is at least as justified as yours.

Answer (score -1):

Try this as a test and you will see you just need to set the same model on all the text fields that need to have the same information.

```
JTextField t1 = new JTextField();
JTextField t2 = new JTextField();
PlainDocument doc = new PlainDocument();
t1.setDocument(doc);
t2.setDocument(doc);
setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
add(t1);
add(t2);
```